# How to halve a cake recipe?

Tags: baking, cake

An entire cake is too much food (and temptation!) for me and my husband. Generally speaking, how do I halve a cake recipe? I have heard you can't just cut everything in half due to the way baking powder & soda react.

A particular recipe I would like to cut in half is [Red Velvet Cake](http://www.justrightmenus.com/recipe.php?id=123).

(I would then just put all the batter into one cake pan instead of 2.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have halved cake recipes before without issue. The most complicated thing to worry about is halving an odd number of eggs, but [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/how-do-you-halve-a-recipe-that-calls-for-1-egg) addresses that. The finished product was indistinguishable from the full recipe.

**Edit**

One thing to note. In your specific case, because it's a two-layer cake, halving is simple because you're only cooking a single layer. Halving other cakes, such as a pound cake, or a bundt cake involves adjustments to the cooking time. A halved cake will cook much quicker, and could possibly need a lower temperature as well as a decreased cooking time.

Answer (score 0):

I halve cake recipes quite often and just round up the number of eggs.   So if the full recipe calls for 3 eggs, instead of trying to figure out 1 and 1/2 I put in 2.  So far, so good.