# What can I do with frozen eggs?

Tags: eggs, freezing, culinary-uses

Although a previous [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5021/3418) asks if raw eggs can be frozen, my eggs froze, in the shell, because the chicken coop into which they were delivered was very cold last week.

I thawed the eggs, and they seem fine, except that the yolks are solid / gelatinous. This means that scrambled eggs are out, at least as I know them.

What else can be done with these eggs; this will probably happen again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best I can offer you comes from [Functionality of Proteins in Food](http://books.google.ca/books?id=2-eBqE5MzAYC&pg=PA354&lpg=PA354&source=bl&ots=mt0s5JQ7sP&sig=yb9aJfvUX4BbrBoDhi-veNi3wVA&hl=en&ei=rFgNTYazG9mJnAf30MikDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The gelation of egg yolk can be partially reversed by heating after thawing.  This treatment improves the functional properties of proteins.  The stiffness of the gels obtained after frozen storage can be reduced by more than 50% and become pourable at 21° C by heating up to 45° C for 1 h.

Eggs don't actually start to set until you hit 63° C, so if I had previously-frozen eggs, I would heat them as the above paragraph suggests.  Just be very careful not to use too much heat.

You won't get *perfect* eggs, but they'll be edible.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can freeze eggs, then make scrambled eggs.

I peeled 4 frozen eggs and put them in a bowl. I zapped them for 1 min in the microwave to thaw, then whipped the eggs and zapped for 1 more minute.  I had beautiful delicious scrambled eggs.

Answer (score 4):

I like to freeze whole egg yolks then plop them into hot Asian soups or use as a garnish. They have an amazing mouth-feel this way. They're also good with butter spread on toast.

Comment: Interesting. Can you keep the yolks intact that way?

Answer (score 2):

Thaw them out, boil them. Then pickle them.

Comment: I was told that it is not necessary to thaw them out, just don't have them on to high of a boil when putting them in.

Answer (score -2):

Before you freeze the raw eggs (1) add half ts of salt with every cup of raw eggs, poke the yoke mix with the white and put in freezer bag or container and freeze them, for savory or main dishes. (2) add 1Tbs of sugar for each cup of raw eggs mix the yoke with the white and freeze for baking and desserts. They can stay good up to 1 year in the freezer. The salt and sugar is to keep the eggs from becoming gelatinous. I hope I did help

Comment: good idea, but the eggs are frozen before I get to them.

Answer (score -2):

Peel it then batter in tempura batter. Tada, soft-boiled egg tempura!

Comment: The eggs are no longer frozen. How can you peel and batter them if they're not cooked?