# Frozen eggs in the shell: thaw and cook or trash them?

Tags: eggs, freezing

I wanted to scramble some eggs and when I cracked them they were frozen solid. Could I have cooked them? I just threw them out.

Can you thaw frozen eggs and cook them???

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10280/67

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do with frozen eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10280/what-can-i-do-with-frozen-eggs)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can thaw frozen eggs and cook them, the only thing is that the consistency will change and the yolk tends to get lumpy. I wouldn't recommend trying to bake with them but they'll make fine scrambled eggs.