# How can I get frozen egg whites out of the ice tray?

Tags: freezing, egg-whites

I read in [Can raw eggs be frozen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5021/can-raw-eggs-be-frozen) that you can freeze eeg whites and use them later.

I saw [this suggestion](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/827/7085) about using an ice tray to make frozen egg white cubes (which makes it easier later on when you want to use a few eeg whites out of a frozen batch).

My problem is, the frozen cubes won't come out of the ice tray! They seem to expand or for some reason stick to the tray very hard. I needed to melt them by running the back of the tray under hot water to get them out.

Obviously I can't use any oil or anything like that in the tray to prevent sticking.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Anything you use will freeze and not let go. I get the egg whites out by dipping the tray in warm water for a second. You should post your warm water solution as the answer and accept your own answer. :)

Comment: Isn't this normal? My water ice cubes don't come out of the tray either if I don't run hot water. Unless I am using a silicone mold of course, but it seems that yours is of the normal, hard variety.

Comment: Really! I have always used plastic trays and if you twist or bend them they let go of the water ice cubes, or sometimes I need to tap the back with a spoon or something!

Comment: @rumtscho completely depends on the ice cube trays.  More expensive ones seem to release *a lot*.  Just a slight twist of the frame causes them all to 'pop' out.  On cheap ones, I've had to resort to hot water.

Comment: @rfusca- that's true for ice but I've never had a cube tray let go of frozen egg whites.

Comment: @rfusca A simple twist works fine for $5 ice trays from Target.  I do notice that older trays that have been over-twisted don't release very well, at which point I just buy new ones

Comment: @Davy 8 5 dollars *is* the more expensive ones. Walmart has a 3 for 2 dollars or something that are *terrible*

Comment: @Sob - ya, I was just addressing rum's comment.  If you're going to do egg whites much, try silicone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to sum up, so far, we have:

- use a silicon tray, there should be no problems there.
- put the tray in warm water for a short while and they would let go.