# What do I do with one cracked egg?

Tags: eggs

I just fumbled one of the eggs I was going to hard-boil for dinner. It's just a slight crack, but enough that there's a bit of albumen seeping – I definitely can't hard-boil it now.

I have no plans for *one* raw egg. What's a quick and simple way to use it so it doesn't go to waste?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, this was closed because of the 'polling' part of the close reason - there are just way too many simple ways you can cook eggs on their own (scrambling, frying, poaching, baking...) and still more ways to use them in things. You can often get good answers in [chat] for things like this though!

Comment: @Jefromi Thanks; right, of course. I should have known better too, since this isn't my first Stack… I guess that's egg on my face. \*ducks\*

Answer (score 5):

If you didn't originally plan on using the egg out of shell, there is no reason you need to do it now. The egg if put in a sealed container can last 2-4 days out of shell according to stilltasty.com.

If you don't plan to use the egg within that time frame then you can extend that time farther by freezing the egg: [Can raw eggs be frozen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5021/can-raw-eggs-be-frozen).

Answer (score 3):

You could break open the egg into a ramekin or coffee mug and place it in the microwave for 2 minutes. Enjoy it then or the next day.

A little tip if you want it to come out in one piece, spray a little pan release inside the mug or ramekin.

Answer (score 0):

Lightly stir it (to break the yoke but not mix it all together).

Throw it in a pan with some butter, spring onion, capsicum, and cheese and ham if you have it.

Season with salt and pepper, and either eat it like that, or put it on buttered bread.